# WCF post file limit

Tags: wcf, readerquotas

I have WCF service hosted in SharePoint that works fine some time ago, but it doesn't work now and I don't understand why it happened. I try post file to the service and get error 400(badrequest) if file less 16Kb no errors. I change my config file so

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentSetService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost/_vti_bin/documentset.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentSetService" contract="Sitronics.AFK.BoD.SharePoint.Services.Services.IDocumentSetService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDocumentSetService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I need modify maxArrayLength on the server side, how can I do it? Service host configured in the following way

```
public class DocumentSetServiceFactory : MultipleBaseAddressBasicHttpBindingServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var sh = base.CreateServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);

            sh.Opening += sh_Opening;

            return sh;
        }

        public override ServiceHostBase CreateServiceHost(string constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            var sh = base.CreateServiceHost(constructorString, baseAddresses);

            sh.Opening += sh_Opening;

            return sh;
        }

        void sh_Opening(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var sh = (ServiceHostBase)sender;

            LoggingService.LogDebug("DocumentServiceHost:Opening");

            if (sh.Description != null)
            {

                LoggingService.LogDebug("DocumentServiceHost:Description is not null");

                foreach (var endPoint in sh.Description.Endpoints)
                {

                    LoggingService.LogDebug(string.Format("DocumentServiceHost:FOR ENDPOINT {0}", endPoint.Address));

                    var bec = endPoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
                    var transport = bec.Find<TransportBindingElement>();

                    if (transport != null)
                    {
                        LoggingService.LogDebug(string.Format("DocumentServiceHost:TRANSPORT {0}",transport.Scheme));


                        transport.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 5242880;
                        transport.MaxBufferPoolSize = 5242880;
                    }
                }
            }
        }        
    }
```